# need help fixing the link's clickable area

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Was just amusing myself with a little useless site, practicing this and that.
I came across a problem, where the link is only clickable on the left, not the right.

how it looks:
div, inside it a header(2) with in it a link

```
        <div class="button one"><h2><a href="#">example</a></h2></div>
```

It has a right border, a hover function and quite a width. It is absolute positioned. Been trying around a bit a came up with following code (it is a bith messy, sorry)

```
.button{
position:absolute;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
width:300px;
height:70px;
background-color:#999999;
border-left:solid 7px #FF6600;
border-bottom:solid 1px #FF6600;
border-top:solid 1px #FF6600;

}

.button h2{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:1,5em;
}
a{
margin:0px;
display:block;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:20px;

}
a:hover{
background-color:#FF6600;
}
```

problem: links are only links up about 1/2 the width. They background color of the hover changes the complete area, but only works when the mouse is in that link area. Not sure where I missed something. All help is appreciated!

For those who want to look into the css and html files themselves, i put them in a test.rar file:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/pe42e0

Comment: What part of this is not clickable? http://jsfiddle.net/HbMaP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the image **#content_image_1** is positioned above your buttons. If you remove the `z-index: 1;` from that image, your buttons work as intended. Albeit with your image behind the buttons.

Comment: Oh yes, that I did not think of that myself! Explains a lot of other things as well. Thanks!
@Hefty Hijacker: Any idea how I can still use this image and the divs? I used it to hide the end of the divs. So every part that comes over the image is cut off.