# Hit testing below the clicked element

Tags: html, css, image, mouseevent, transparent

On succession of a previous question I tried to find out if the next thing is possible:

Take you have a render, like a soccer player with a transparant background. You add this render to your html & css. The transparant parts are now part of the image 'box'; you can't click on links under the image transparant parts, but you can see them.

Is it possible to make these links clickable? Thus having the image as highest z-index, but still have the links clickable and working.

(the links have a lower z-index because their background then stops under the image, giving a nicer design)

(Or said otherwise: have a .png image with a transparant background not shown as a box, but as only the colored pixels. Preferable only in html/css)

I think it is not possible, to be honest. If you do not yet understand my question, maybe my previous will help you:
[need help fixing the link's clickable area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671622/need-help-fixing-the-links-clickable-area?noredirect=1#comment22245821_15671622)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) to make an event (click in this case) bubble through to the layer below.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible from what I'm aware of. However you can do similar things to what you want that may be useful:

- Turn an area into a link using [`<map>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/map)
- Use [`pointer-events:none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/pointer-events) so that clicks are ignored on the top element

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 provides the non-standard [`msElementsFromPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#The_msElementsFromPoint_method) method that allows you to "peek below" an element; you can do that inside the click handler and determine if the click point overlaps an anchor. If it does, triggering that element's click event would do what needs to be done.

Unfortunately I am not aware of similar functionality for other browsers or earlier versions of IE.